# Docker wordpress error with sql connection

Tags: mysql, docker, wordpress

***Hello there, I get this error from wordpress container on logs.***

> MySQL Connection Error: (2054) The server requested authentication
>   method unknown to the client
>
> 2018-06-16T14:48:04.784571621Z
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): The server requested authentication
>   method unknown to the client [caching_sha2_password] in Standard input
>   code on line 22
>
> 2018-06-16T14:48:04.784697952Z
>
> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2054): The server requested
>   authentication method unknown to the client in Standard input code on
>   line 22

***The commands that I use was exactly as I saw them (im new)***

```
docker pull mysql

docker run --name easql -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abc123 -d mysql:latest

docker pull wordpress

docker run --name ealocal -link easql:mysql -p 8080:80 -d wordpress
```

***After those exactly commands  on video everything works great.
 On my machine the wordpress container stops by itself. Any  help ? Thanks !***

Answer (score 1):

Type at -link (should be --link)

The following environment variables have to be passed.
`-e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=`
`-e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=`

In your case, y

`docker run --name ealocal --link easql:mysql -p 8080:80 -d -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=abc123 wordpress`

Your container should start now. If any db related errors in logs, follow below.

`docker exec -it easql bash   == bash shell inside DB server`

```
mysql -u root -p   -- Login to DB server
Enter password: abc123
```

## paste below command

`ALTER USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';`
`exit`
`exit`

Then start new container:

`docker run --name ealocal --link easql:mysql -p 8080:80 -d -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=root -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=abc123 wordpress`

Refer to official wordpress docx:
https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress